# RCurl installation error

Tags: r

I have R 3.2.0 in redhat.
I am trying to install RCurl, but get the following error

```
myUTF8.c: In function \u2018StringValue\u2019:
myUTF8.c:284: warning: passing argument 1 of \u2018Rf_mkCharLenCE\u2019 from incompatible pointer type
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/home/gowthan/Downloads/R-3.2.0/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o RCurl.so base64.o curl.o curlInit.o curl_base64.o enums.o json.o memoryManagement.o myUTF8.o -L/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-5R4zB/workspace/build/Curl/Curl-7.18.1.155.6782/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/curl/install/lib -lcurl -L/opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Fbopenssl/Fbopenssl-0.0.4.504.7765/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib -lfbopenssl -L/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-5R4zB/workspace/build/Curl/Curl-7.18.1.155.6782/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/tmp/brazil-path/[Openssl]lib.libfarm/lib -L/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-k5Vrj/workspace/build/Libxml2/Libxml2-2.7.8.334.176/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/libxml2/install/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm -L/home/gowthan/Downloads/R-3.2.0/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfbopenssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RCurl.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package \u2018RCurl\u2019
* removing \u2018/home/gowthan/Downloads/R-3.2.0/library/RCurl\u2019

The downloaded source packages are in
        \u2018/tmp/RtmpLXPsKI/downloaded_packages\u2019
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("RCurl", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package \u2018XML\u2019 had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("RCurl", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package \u2018RCurl\u2019 had non-zero exit status
```

The build is failing and it does not find lfbopenssl. How do I install that?

EDIT:

```
I already tried : yum -y install libcurl libcurl-devel
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package libcurl available.
No package libcurl-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

I already have curl, curl-devl and openssl installed.

Answer (score 0):

There is warning: `cannot find -lfbopenssl`, so you need to install openssl first: https://www.openssl.org/and then try to perfrom `RCurl` installation one more time.

Try this code:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

As mentioned here: https://github.com/sagemath/cloud/issues/114

**EDIT**

on red-hat try this:

```
yum install openssl
```

Also remember about configuration of openssl and curl.
The configuration of openssl is described here:
http://dev.antoinesolutions.com/openssl

Comment: I am using red hat. And sudo yum -y install libcurl libcurl-devel says there is no package
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package libcurl available.
No package libcurl-devel available.
Nothing to do

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I don't have permission to go inside /etc/pki/CA. Will try to figure something out. But, openssl was already installed and it mush be configured already.

Comment: If I do "where openssl". I get many pathnames. And theory are all configured. How do I make R use it? R says cannot find openssl, even though its available and configured.